# Outlook 2013 Advanced Search for Read/Unread Changes

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-2013

I'm trying to identify all emails that were changed, in my inbox, from Unread status to Read status on 3/7/2017 between 9:30am and 11am (because I accidentally marked them all read, without tracking those with a flag or something else handy.)

Can I make that search using the Advanced View Settings > Filter... function in Outlook 2013?

I tried using the Advanced tab in the Filter popup box to look at emails Modified between those times, but it didn't show these emails.

I can't find another Field in the Advanced tab to search for changes to this email status.

Does anyone know how to make this search, either using the query building capabilities on the Messages, More Choices, or Advanced tabs?  Or by building a query in the SQL tab?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that kind of search is impossible simply because marking an item as read or unread doesn't affect the last modification time.

Comment: Thanks Eric -- I appreciate the response, though I wish it was a different answer